# Can I create BackgroundAudioPlayer and BackgroundAgent?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Can I create multiple agents like BackgroundAudioPlayer and BackgroundAgent for file transfer ?

Answer (score 1):

Neither BackgroundAudioPlayer agent or BackgroundAgent is useful for file transfer due to the very restricted run times that these background processes are allowed.

You should [use the Background File Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202959%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)  ability instead if at all possible. You can create up to 25 transfer requests at a time this way and the OS will keep downloading your files even when your app isn't running as long as the transfer conditions are met.